# Google Deployment Manager: DNS. Removing TXT record also removes A record

Tags: google-cloud-platform, dns, google-deployment-manager

I have a deployment manager configuration for DNS (dns.yaml):

```
imports:
- path: domainorg.jinja

resources:
  - name: domainorg
    type: domainorg.jinja
```

domainorg.jinja contents:

```
resources:
  - type: gcp-types/dns-v1:managedZones
    name: domainorg
    properties:
      description: ''
      dnsName: domain.org.
      visibility: "public"
  - type: gcp-types/dns-v1:resourceRecordSets
    name: domainorgrs
    properties:
      name: 'domain.org.'
      managedZone: "domainorg"
      records:
      - type: A
        ttl: 300
        rrdatas:
        - XXX.XXX.XXX.XXX
  - type: gcp-types/dns-v1:resourceRecordSets
    name: wwwdomainorgrs
    properties:
      name: 'www.domain.org.'
      managedZone: "domainorg"
      records:
      - type: CNAME
        ttl: 300
        rrdatas:
        - domain.org.
  - type: gcp-types/dns-v1:resourceRecordSets
    name: domainorgsgverrs
    properties:
      name: 'domain.org.'
      managedZone: "domainorg"
      records:
      - type: TXT
        ttl: 300
        rrdatas:
        - "google-site-verification=YYY"
```

I performed deployment using cli:

```
gcloud deployment-manager deployments update dns --config dns.yaml
```

It works as expected. But, when I decided to remove TXT record from domainorg.jinja and to update the deployment I've got an unexpected result: google deployment manager removed TXT record with A record and my website fails... Is there any way to remove only TXT record using deployment manager?

Guys, had someone the same problem in the past? I will be very glad to see your solution.

Answer (score 0):

There is a workaround which is already posted in this [github link](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/deploymentmanager-samples/issues/62). Please try if that works on your end.